# Why do I get a JavascriptException "no method 'focus'" when I click on a EditTextCell?

Tags: java, gwt, user-interface

I'm using GWT, building a table.

I would like on of the fields to be a EditTextCell. It renders OK initially, but then when I click on it to make it change into a TextInputCell, I see the following exception in Eclipse:

```
15:13:22.428 [ERROR] [xxx] Uncaught exception escaped

com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError): Object [object Text] has no method 'focus'
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:237)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:132)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:269)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:214)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor252.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:167)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:281)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:531)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:352)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

Relevant code is:

```
private void buildTable() {
  // Create a celltable
  final CellTable<Person> personTable = new CellTable<Person>(KEY_PROVIDER);
  // Create name column
  final EditTextCell nameCell = new EditTextCell();
  Column<Person, String> nameColumn = new Column<Person, String>(nameCell) {
    @Override
    public String getValue(Person person) {
      return person.getName();
    }
  };
  nameColumn.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<Person,String>() {
    public void update(int index, Person object, String value) {
      System.out.println("field updater called");
    }
  });
  // Make the name column sortable.
  nameColumn.setSortable(true);
  personTable.addColumn(nameColumn, "Name");
  // ... and then code for other columns... 
}
```

Does anyone have a clue on why I get the exception that I'm seeing?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the cause of this particular error, but I was suffering with this issue also.

I was able to solve this using a DataProvider, in my case an AsyncDataProvider to be more specific. However, you can use the ListDataProvider in your example. You can find more info about DataProviders at [Google code developer's guide](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellWidgets.html#data-provider).

You may want to check the [GWT Showcase page](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTable), and inspect the sample java code.